# How to copy UWP StorageFile to StorageFolder without creating new DateCreated.DateTime info

Tags: c#, file, uwp, copy

I'm trying to copy a StorageFile to StorageFolder

```
StorageFile timeStampFile = timeStampFiles.First(f => f.Name == sourceFile.Name);

Debug.WriteLine("TS FILE DATE=" + timeStampFile.DateCreated.DateTime); 
//TS FILE DATE=9/6/2018 7:14:43 PM

StorageFile createdCopy = await timeStampFile.CopyAsync(destinationFolder);
Debug.WriteLine("COPIED FILE DATE=" + createdCopy.DateCreated.DateTime);
//COPIED FILE DATE=9/6/2018 7:36:30 PM
```

But DateCreated.DateTime of the created copy is different from the original file. How can I copy file with same DateCreated.DateTime info?

Comment: You are copying the file. i.e, Creating a copy of the file from another folder. That is the reason why date created is different. Try [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.moveasync) or [MoveAndReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.moveandreplaceasync).

Comment: Call [SetFileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime) to set the desired value. This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42799235/1889329) tells you, how to get a file handle from a `StorageFile`.