# How can I get a Win32 HANDLE with FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES access for a StorageFile or StorageFolder in UWP?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, uwp

I am trying to implement Notepad++ style toggling read-only flag for files in an UWP text editor. I tried using [`SetFileAttributesFromApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846630(v=vs.85)) but it fails with `Access to the path is denied` for sensitive file types like Batch files and VBScript files. Then I tried using [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) which requires UWP app to get handle from `StorageFile`. I tried using [`CreateSafeFileHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.windowsruntimestorageextensions.createsafefilehandle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) but it only provides read and write access and the only way to modify attribute is to get write access. Getting write access fails if the file has read only flag enabled or file is drag and dropped to editor. I checked answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799235/how-can-i-get-a-win32-handle-for-a-storagefile-or-storagefolder-in-uwp) question and the only extra access this method specifies is read attribute and delete access. So my question is can I get [`FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants?redirectedfrom=MSDN) access to the handle created from `StorageFile`, if so how do I do that??

Comment: Could you please tell me if the project you are using is a C# UWP project or a C++/WinRT UWP project?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Sorry for not clarifying clearly(I thought the usage of `SafeFileHandle` would be obvious), the project is a uwp C# project with P/Invoking some `winapi` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API to support getting `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` access to the handle created from a `StorageFile` when the `StorageFile` instance has read only flag.

If you want to edit the dragged file in your UWP text editor, you could copy the dragged file into the [LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#application-data-locations). The copied file will have read and write access permission. You could edit the copied file and replace it with the original dragged file with a `FileSavePicker`. Note you could delete the copied file in `LocalFolder` if you don’t need to save it. In this way, you have no need to change the read only flag of a file.